# Animation in core graphics

Tags: swift

I followed this awesome Rey Wenderlich tutorial to make an Bezier arc and increment/decrement values. But how to animate the arch instead of just step-up and step-down?

http://www.raywenderlich.com/90690/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-1

I tried putting animation block in custom property declaration, which I dont think is the right place to do it and xcode doesn't let me do it anyway.

```
    @IBInspectable var counter: Int = 5 {
    didSet {
        if counter <=  NoOfGlasses {
            //the view needs to be refreshed

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
                    setNeedsDisplay()
                }, completion:nil
            )


        }
    }
}
```

Also tried to put the increment in animation block in View controller, didn't work.

```
@IBAction func btnPushButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        self.arcView.counter = self.arcView.counter + 10
        self.counterLabel.text = String(self.arcView.counter)

        }, completion:nil
    )

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you describing this sort of thing?

[image]

That's a simpler example - it's just a drawn triangle - but it's the same idea, if I'm understanding you correctly: we are animating the difference between one drawing and another.

Basically you have two choices. The easy way is to use CAShapeLayer, which animates for you automatically when you change its `path`. The other choice is to do what I'm doing here, which is to create a custom animatable property - in this case, a property representing the x-position of the bottom point of the triangle.