# Animation with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibezierpath, custom-view

I searched a lot for this topic, all answers said that i have to use CAShapeLayer or Layers and ... . the problem is i don't really know how to use them, and i know a solution to my problem; i'd just like to know if there's any way to do this without CAShapeLayer.

I'm trying to make a Star shaped rating view. there's a star, and a rectangle inside it from bottom to top indicating percentage of the rated star.

here is my .h file:

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface FSStarRatingView : UIView

@property (assign, nonatomic) IBInspectable BOOL transparentInside;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat innerRadius; // between 0-1

@property (assign, nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat percentage; // between 0-1
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *fillColor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *unfilledColor; // works if transparentInside is YES
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *strokeColor;

- (void)setPercentage:(CGFloat)percentage withAnimationDuration:(CGFloat)duration;
```

and here is my .m file

```
- (UIBezierPath *)starShapedBezierPath {
    CGPoint points[10];
    //  points[0] = CGPointMake(self.center.x, 0);
    CGFloat outterRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2;
    CGFloat startDegree = 3.0 * M_PI_2;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(outterRadius, outterRadius * 2.0/1.85);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i+=2) {
        points[i] = CGPointMake(center.x + outterRadius * cos(startDegree),
                                center.y + outterRadius * sin(startDegree));
        startDegree += 0.4 * M_PI;
    }

    CGFloat innerRadius = self.innerRadius * outterRadius;
    startDegree = M_PI_2;
    for (int i = 5; i < 15; i+=2) {
        points[i%10] = CGPointMake(center.x + innerRadius * cos(startDegree),
                                   center.y + innerRadius * sin (startDegree));
        startDegree += 0.4 * M_PI;
    }

    UIBezierPath *star = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [star moveToPoint:points[0]];
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        [star addLineToPoint:points[i]];
    [star closePath];
    return star;
}

- (void)setPercentage:(CGFloat)percentage {
    _percentage = percentage;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)setPercentage:(CGFloat)percentage withAnimationDuration:(CGFloat)duration{
    [UIView
     animateWithDuration:duration
     animations:^{
         self.percentage = percentage;
     }];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *star = [self starShapedBezierPath];
    star.lineWidth = 1.0;
    [self.strokeColor setStroke];
    [star stroke];
    [star addClip];
    CGFloat topBottomOffset = 0.15 * self.frame.size.width / 4.0;
    CGFloat availableHeight = self.frame.size.height - 2.0 * topBottomOffset;
    CGFloat usedHeight = availableHeight * self.percentage;
    if (! self.transparentInside) {
        UIBezierPath *unusedPercentageRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, topBottomOffset, self.frame.size.width, availableHeight - usedHeight)];
        [self.unfilledColor setFill];
        [unusedPercentageRect fill];
    }

    UIBezierPath *usedPercentageRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, topBottomOffset + availableHeight - usedHeight, self.frame.size.width, usedHeight)];
    [self.fillColor setFill];
    [usedPercentageRect fill];
    [star addClip];
}
```

I know it is possible to do it with 2 subviews and animating their frame with animation, just wondering if there's a way to do it directly with Bezierpaths...
thanks

Comment: Do you mean this sort of thing? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31258793/341994

Comment: This is exactly what i mean @matt

Comment: Well, then there you go. My answer there is the answer you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i still don't know how to do it @matt, i read your answer there, you said either use CAShapeLayer, or a _custom animatable property_ . that's what i "think" i'm doing here, but apparently i'm not. i wanted to use percentage as a custom animatable property which every-time percentage changes, drawn picture change. I thought it will do it, but it won't :(

Comment: Custom animatable property: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_making_a_property_animatable